# What do the comments at the end php-src c files mean?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

If you scroll to the end, there should be comments like these. What do they do, what do they mean?

```
/*
 * Local variables:
 * tab-width: 4
 * c-basic-offset: 4
 * indent-tabs-mode: t
 * End:
 */
```

I found a reference to GNU Emacs, but I am not familiar with it and a quick read didn't help much either. Is it a script that later generates emacs customizations from them?

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/reflection/php_reflection.h

Comment: It's emacs stuff, read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Style-Variables.html#Style-Variables) and [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Emacs *File Variables*. They tell the Emacs text editor to set various per-buffer options. In your example, it instructs it on the preferred indentation style when editing that program, so that it will indent each block by 4 columns.

See [Specifying File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) in the Emacs manual for more details.